# How to convert VS VSTO Workbook project to VSTO Add-in

Tags: vsto, add-in, project-conversion

I have created VSTO Workbook project in VS 2019. but later I realized that VSTO ADD-IN is sufficient. 
can anyone help how to convert the project to ADD-IN.
I have checked project properties , nothing hints to a solution

I can't find anything useful describing this problem easiest way I can create new project and recreate already existing functionality.

Comment: There is no conversion functionality - you need to create a new Add-in project. But you can use copy/paste to bring across code that works with the object model of whichever Office application youre working with. Without more details there's not much else anyone can tell you...